# SSH to a VMWare virtual machine with a static IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, vmware

I've been playing around with VMWare, and I am trying to get a little network of local, virtual servers communicating with each other, and being able to SSH from one to another. I've set up an Ubuntu 18.04 servers, with static IP addresses and OpenSSH during the installation phase.

After the setup, if I run `ipconfig`, I see that the new address I chose, e.g. `192.168.1.123`, and I can `ping 192.168.1.124` (the other server) from this server, but when I try and connect to either via SSH in PuTTY on Windows, the connection times out. My network adapter is set to Bridged but I have left the box 'Replicate physical network connection state' blank. I can't seem to `apt-get update` to work either, it says '`Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com`'.

I am relatively new to both VMWare and Linux Server as a whole, so any assistence would be extremely helpful as I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Comment: Which VMware product are you using to host these systems?

Comment: VMWare Workstation Pro 15

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Update**

I figured out what my issue was, I essentially couldn't connect to the internet via my laptop's wifi. For legacy sake, I solved this issue by:

- Going to Edit - Virtual Network Editor
- Selecting VMnet0 (This is used for bridged connections)
- Then changed the 'Bridged to:' dropdown from Automatic to my Wifi card

This seemingly has solved all of my issues.